# PostgreSQL and C# Datatypes

Tags: c#, postgresql, types

I searched type convertion table between PostgreSQL and C#, but I couldn't find anything.
I'll research empty cell on above table if I have time.
But if you know the web page which has these information, I'm very appropriate to your help.

```
Postgre Type --->C# Type

bigint --->Int64

bigserial --->

bit [ (n) ] --->Byte[]

bit varying [ (n) ] --->Byte

boolean --->Boolean

box --->

bytea --->Byte[]

character varying [ (n) ] ---> String

character --->String

cidr

circle 

date --->DateTime

double precision --->Double

inet

integer --->Int32

interval [ (p) ] --->TimeSpan

line 

lseg 

macaddr

money

numeric [ (p, s) ] --->Decimal

decimal [ (p, s) ] --->Decimal

path  

point 

polygon 

real --->Single

smallint --->Int16

serial 

text --->String

time [ (p) ] [ without time zone ] --->

time [ (p) ] with time zone --->

timestamp [ (p) ] [ without time zone ] --->

timestamp [ (p) ] with time zone --->

tsquery 

tsvector 

txid_snapshot

uuid --->Guid

xml
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Maybe you can find something looking through the documentation of
[Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/doc), which is an implementation of a .NET Data Provider for PostgreSQL.

[This page of the documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html) actually contains a complete table of what you are looking for. Search for "4. Current Npgsql Status" - "Supported data types". There is a nice table with all PostgreSQL data types and their correspondents in .NET.

```
Postgresql  NpgsqlDbType System.DbType Enum .NET System Type
----------  ------------ ------------------ ----------------
int8        Bigint       Int64              Int64
bool        Boolean      Boolean            Boolean
bytea       Bytea        Binary             Byte[]
date        Date         Date               DateTime
float8      Double       Double             Double
int4        Integer      Int32              Int32
money       Money        Decimal            Decimal
numeric     Numeric      Decimal            Decimal
float4      Real         Single             Single
int2        Smallint     Int16              Int16
text        Text         String             String
time        Time         Time               DateTime
timetz      Time         Time               DateTime
timestamp   Timestamp    DateTime           DateTime
timestamptz TimestampTZ  DateTime           DateTime
interval    Interval     Object             TimeSpan
varchar     Varchar      String             String
inet        Inet         Object             IPAddress
bit         Bit          Boolean            Boolean
uuid        Uuid         Guid               Guid
array       Array        Object             Array
```

Comment: Not sure if this is out date but I had some troubles getting a DateTime object to be converted to a Postgresql "time" type.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129558/nhibernate-postgresql-datetime-to-time-conversion/6138382. I needed to use a TimeSpan object to get it to save as a Postgresql time object.

Comment: @Spilarix Thank you. Fixed the links.

Comment: This table is wrong, the DB type TIME can be negative, in fact it is the SQL recommended type for storing the result of one timestamp minus another timestamp - i.e. it is the recommended type for storing timespans. DB TIME must map to C# TimeSpan because C# DateTime cannot hold negative values and will thus fail to convert. DB Time is specified as intended to be used both for storing absolute AND relative time, and has a valid range from -hh:mm to +hh:mm, where I belive hh is approx 850 hours, but I don't remember of the top of my head.

Comment: hi! what about jsonb postgresql type? 
I have a data column whose type is jsonb. And I map it to a string property. It seems incorrect as I am having this error Npgsql.PostgresException : 42804: column "data" is of type jsonb but expression is of type text.