# NHibernate Postgresql DateTime to Time Conversion

Tags: .net, nhibernate, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate, npgsql

I'm using Fluent NHibernate to configure my mappings everything works when reading data but when trying to insert or update records that have a Postgresql type of Time I get the error message

`"ERROR: 42804: column \"run_time\" is of type time with time zone but expression is of type timestamp without time zone"`

It looks like NHibernate might be confused on which DbType to convert the DateTime to as you can see from [PostgreSQL and C# Datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845458/postgresql-and-c-datatypes) that there are several DbTypes that DateTime map to.

I also tried specifying a custom type for this column from IUserType but on the NullSafeSet override I get a NullReferenceError

```
public override void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
{
    var obj = (DateTime)value;

    NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.Time.NullSafeSet(cmd, obj, index);
}
```

Is there some type of hint I can provide to either tell NHibernate to convert the DateTime to a Postgresql "time" type?  Or can I achieve this by the IUserType and I'm just doing something wrong?

Comment: How do you currently have this column mapped in your fluent mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out!

Apparently the conversion sheet I [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845458/postgresql-and-c-datatypes) to is either wrong or out of date.  It turns out that a System.TimeSpan object is what's needed for Npgsql to do a proper conversion to a Postgresql "time" object.  It seems odd to me that they would try to convert something that represents a difference between two time's into what we think of as HH:mm:ss but that's the way it is.

Rather than change the type of my RunTime property from System.DateTime to System.TimeSpan I've instead created a custom IUserType and have overriden NullSafeSet to look like

```
public override void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
{
    var obj = (DateTime)value;

    ((IDbDataParameter) cmd.Parameters[index]).Value = new TimeSpan(0, obj.Hour, obj.Minute, obj.Second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to fix this issue by defining your mapping like this:

```
Map(x => x.RunTime, "run_time").CustomSqlType("time");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think NH has invalid definitions for data types, you can report them here:
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH
+ in the mean time you can drive your own dialect to solve that. something like:

```
public class CustomDialect : OriginalDialect
{
    public CustomDialect()
    {
      //... add your new definitions here to override default values    
    }
}
```

now you can use it this way:

```
var dbType = XyzConfiguration.Standard
                       ...
                       .Dialect<CustomDialect>();
```