# Float on PostgreSQL using c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, insert, floating-point

Im using this

this is the data type im sending in the cmd:

> NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Real;

here im cheking that is a numeric value:

> ```
>    public bool IsNumeric(String value){
>         try{
>             float.Parse(value);
>             return true;
>         }
>         catch(Exception e){
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
> ```

And here is the alter table:

> ALTER TABLE "Medicine" ADD COLUMN "Price" real;
>   ALTER TABLE "Medicine" ALTER COLUMN "Price" SET NOT NULL;

The table data type is Real too, thats how i can save "float" cuz it seen that PostgreSQL doesnt have a float. Ive tried with double, money, numeric, and still doesnt work. The numbers is inserted in the table, but w/o the ".", for example, i writte 12.34 and 1234 is inserted. Already checked everything when debugging.

How can i solve this?

Comment: postgresql has two floating point types: `real` and `double precision`. Try `select 1::double precision, 1::real;`

Answer (score 2):

First of all your `isNumeric` function is a bad way to check if a string value is numeric, this is a terrific use of **try-catch** construct ...

You should check if the string is numeric with a regular expression like the following :

```
public static bool IsNumeric(string value)
{
    bool match;
    //regular expression to match numeric values
    string pattern = "(^[-+]?\\d+(,?\\d*)*\\.?\\d*([Ee][-+]\\d*)?$)|(^[-+]?\\d?(,?\\d*)*\\.\\d+([Ee][-+]\\d*)?$)";
    Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    match = regEx.Match(value).Success;
    return match;
}
```

Then to insert a REAL value into the table you should convert it into the Single .NET datatype, take a look at the table in [this question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845458/postgresql-and-c-sharp-datatypes) .

Comment: I think Double.TryParse is a better way to check if a string is actually a decimal number...

Comment: I think that using a try-catch construct when it is not really needed is a bad solution.

Comment: May i know why is it THAT terrific? :/ i saw this in this same forum.