# Postgresql and C data types

Tags: c, database, api, postgresql, libpq

Is there a mapping between Postgresql data types to C data types

Similar to this question

[PostgreSQL and C# Datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845458/postgresql-and-c-sharp-datatypes)

Comment: You want do server-side programming or client-side programming?

Comment: @leeduhem client-side programming

Comment: The [libpq documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq.html) may be helpful. That is all I got.

Answer (score 2):

There's a tool specifically for that for client-side programming: [libpqtypes](http://libpqtypes.esilo.com/).

For server-side programming, i.e. PostgreSQL extensions written in C and running in the PostgreSQL server executable, you need to use PostgreSQL's APIs directly.