# Is there a class that automatically converts .NET framework types to PostgreSQL types?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, type-systems

In order to write sql queries, I need to be able to take a .NET type and get the string for the PostgreSQL type. For example, I need to go from

```
typeof(int) --> "int"
```

It's tricky because typeof(int) is System.Int32. I have found some tables, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845458/postgresql-and-c-sharp-datatypes), but I'm wondering if there's a class that automatically does it rather than having to code all the mappings myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably that would work:

```
public static class DotNetTypeToPostgreSqlType
{
    public static string GetPostgreType(object o)
    {
        if (o is Int64)
        {
            return "int8";
        }
        if (o is Boolean)
        {
            return "bool";
        }
        if (o is Byte[])
        {
            return "bytea";
        }
        if (o is DateTime)
        {
            return "date";
        }
        if (o is Double)
        {
            return "float8";
        }
        if (o is Int32)
        {
            return "int4";
        }
        if (o is Decimal)
        {
            return "money";
        }
        if (o is Decimal)
        {
            return "numeric";
        }
        if (o is Single)
        {
            return "float4";
        }
        if (o is Int16)
        {
            return "int2";
        }
        if (o is String)
        {
            return "text";
        }
        if (o is DateTime)
        {
            return "time";
        }
        if (o is DateTime)
        {
            return "timetz";
        }
        if (o is DateTime)
        {
            return "timestamp";
        }
        if (o is DateTime)
        {
            return "timestamptz";
        }
        if (o is TimeSpan)
        {
            return "interval";
        }
        if (o is String)
        {
            return "varchar";
        }
        if (o is IPAddress)
        {
            return "inet";
        }
        if (o is Boolean)
        {
            return "bit";
        }
        if (o is Guid)
        {
            return "uuid";
        }
        if (o is Array)
        {
            return "array";
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown postgresql type");
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha thanks for writing it out for me. I guess there isn't an official class, which is kind of annoying, but this works great. Thanks!